# how to make file content as base64 encoded before making zip file

Tags: c#

I have a directory where I have `CSV` files which I need to first encode the file content as `base64` string and then make it as `zip` file.

I am able to make file as zip with below code, but in between on the fly how to make file content as base64 encoded? Thanks!

```
 var csvFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Temp", "*.csv")
            .Select(f => new FileInfo(f));

        foreach (var file in csvFiles)
        {
            using (var newFile = ZipFile.Open($@"C:\tmp\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)}.zip",
                ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                newFile.CreateEntryFromFile($@"C:\Temp\{file.Name}",
                    file.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here - you're using something perfectly capable of working with arbitrary binary input which then attempts to compress it's input. But instead of doing that, you first want to bloat the input by converting to base 64? It's using two techniques that pull in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the base64 string, convert it to a byte array, and then create the archive entry from the byte array (by creating a stream).

Something like this should do the job:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
var csvFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.csv");   // This already returns a `FileInfo[]`.

foreach (var file in csvFiles)
{
    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName);
    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
    var base64Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64String);

    string newFilePath = $@"C:\tmp\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)}.zip";
    using (var newFile = ZipFile.Open(newFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        // You might want to change the extension 
        // since the file is no longer in CSV format.
        var zipEntry = newFile.CreateEntry(file.Name);

        using (var base64Stream = new MemoryStream(base64Bytes))
        using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
        {
            base64Stream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could save the base64 string to a temporary file, create the entry from *that* file, and then delete it; but I don't prefer writing dummy data to the disk when the job can be done in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding your motives or other problems (conceptual or otherwise)

Here is a fully *streamed* solution with minimal allocations (let's be nice to your Large Object Heap). The `CryptoStream` with `ToBase64Transform`, is just a way to stream base64 encoding

```
var csvFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Temp");
using var outputStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Test.zip", FileMode.Create);
using var archive = new ZipArchive(outputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
foreach (var file in csvFiles)
{
   using var inputFile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   using var base64Stream = new CryptoStream(inputFile, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
   var entry = archive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
   using var zipStream = entry.Open();
   base64Stream.CopyTo(zipStream);
}
```